# RPi: Can I output a jpg of my camera + an overlay with the picamera library?

Tags: opencv, camera, overlay, transparent, raspberry-pi3

I'm currently pulling frames from my picamera and overlaying a transparent red box.  This works great in preview.  Can I output this image to a jpg?

If not, do I need to use OpenCV?

Thanks!
/e

Comment: Go ahead and try it, then let us know. At that point perhaps you will have an actual programming question that we can help you with.

Comment: Thanks for the help, SunSparc.  I haven't been able to find a way to get both layers to show up in a capture, and the documentation I've found doesn't mention a way to do it (though it stops short of saying flat out that you cannot).  I believe the next step is OpenCV, but maybe there's something I'm overlooking, or another lighter weight option is available.  I think the question is justified.

Comment: The forum is for looking at coding problems - sample code that doesn't work or needs some type of tweak or optimization. In any case it's for code, not really for general discussions of what tools and methods to use.

Comment: Have you seen this resource: http://answers.opencv.org/questions/